# python error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NLTK'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, nltk

Using Ubuntu terminal, when I type python then write import nltk, the package does work, but when I use the 'import nltk' inside a .py file , and run the command :  python pyfile.py, I get this message:  `error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NLTK'`

I tried nearly everything from installing pip3 to reinstalling nltk in python3, what could be the problem? note I am using python 3.6

Here is the code:

```
from NLTK.corpus import stopwords
stopWords = stopwords.words('english')
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopWords)
```

Comment: Please show us the exact code in `pyfile.py` that raises the error. Module names are case-sensitive and it looks like your code actually says `import NLTK`.

Comment: Did you install the module on your system using `sudo pip install -U nltk` ?

Comment: yes I did  install it using  pip install -U nltk

Comment: I added the code in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downcasing it like this `from nltk.corpus import stopwords`

Comment: @Youcef: at least your error message should've changed

Comment: @Youcef Can you print the output of the error when you use 
`from nltk.corpus import stopwords`
instead of `from NLTK.corpus import stopwords`

Comment: No the output didn't change, its always the same error:     from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'

Comment: Ok i figured out the problem, i had an old  py file named nltk in the same directory of my py file, thus it  was interferring with the import, how stupid I am :) , now it is working fine, Sorry and thanks all!